# Weird jQuery Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone please explain why jQuery automatically sets a variable using the ids in a HTML document? I am using jsFiddle to test this behaviour with jQuery 1.11.0

```
<div id ="hero"></div>
```

```js
alert(hero);
```

This displays the DOM Object.

Comment: Can you share fiddle link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=hEmq7icpSP

Comment: This is a behaviour of native JS - nothing to do with jQuery.